# Stream windows audio to linux

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have a setup with quicksynergy allowing me to use mouse keyboard and shared pastedbin between my small windows machine and my main machine running ubuntu.

It's phenomenal for playing windows-only games and running other windows-only software because there's no latency at all in the input.

the only problem is I'd like to have the windows audio in my linux.

I saw this https://superuser.com/a/708908/350509 which I thought was a clean solution. the issue with that is the user only explains how to stream linux audio to windows and says nothing about how to do the opposite.

Is there any way to do this that I could automate for startup on both machines?

Answer (score 1):

I've altered a program found on internet and created [WLStream](https://github.com/rsegecin/WLStream). It enables you to stream audio from a Windows output device so Pulse Audio will be able to play it back on a Linux host. The communication between the two is done with plink from Putty. There's a delay in the audio stream caused by the network, I'm sure if you alter the privilege on the TCP packet sent from plink or change your router's configuration as you would for VOIP it'll reduce the audio's stream lag but my research didn't go any further. WLStream can be compiled using Visual Studio 2017 and there's a pre-compiled from the last version [here](https://github.com/rsegecin/WLStream/blob/858cef3365997910b0f11756e4c83e97e609d552/Debug/loopback-capture.exe).